# game maker studio transferring multiple variables to a script

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-1.4

```
var am = random_range(2,9)
Blood(dir,am);

for (i = 0; i < am; i ++)
{
    bl = instance_create(x,y,Obj_Blood);
    bl.dir = dir
}
```

When the script is run, I want to transfer multiple variables across from the object to the script.  It works if I use `Blood(dir);` but not if I add `am`.  How can I use both variables in the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use argument0, argument1, ... inside the script

   `var dir = argument0
   var am = argument1`
2. You can also use outer variables inside the script (I suppose it's almost your case) but it's more complicated. It's like a method of class that uses private variables inside the object, so better be sure that script is using object variables and not using some not declared (and it's a pitfall because GML easy creates variables).